# Select from one table where not in another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database on my computer, and there are two tables in it.

This is the first one:

```
SELECT  
    [ParticipantID]
    ,[ParticipantName]
    ,[ParticipantNumber]
    ,[PhoneNumber]
    ,[Mobile]
    ,[Email]
    ,[Address]
    ,[Notes]
    ,[IsDeleted]
    ,[Gender]
    ,[DOB]
FROM 
    [Gym].[dbo].[Participant]
```

and this is the second one

```
SELECT  
    [ParticipationID]
    ,[ParticipationNumber]
    ,[ParticpationTypeID]
    ,[AddedByEmployeeID]
    ,[AddDate]
    ,[ParticipantID]
    ,[TrainerID]
    ,[ParticipationDate]
    ,[EndDate]
    ,[Fees]
    ,[PaidFees]
    ,[RemainingFees]
    ,[IsPeriodParticipation]
    ,[NoOfVisits]
    ,[Notes]
    ,[IsDeleted]
FROM 
    [Gym].[dbo].[Participation]
```

Now I need to write a T-SQL query that can return

```
SELECT 
    Participant.ParticipantNumber,
    Participation.ParticipationDate,
    Participation.EndDate
FROM
    Participation
WHERE 
    Participant.ParticipantID = Participation.ParticipantID;
```

and I'm going to be thankful

Comment: Did you actually have a question? Or did you just want to share your query?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. I've removed the incorrect tag for you. In relation to your question(?), I suggest looking up the `JOIN` syntax: [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) & [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: its mysql query and i dont know how to wright it in mssql query

Comment: when i tried the query above i gat this error The multi-part identifier "Participant.ParticipantID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Participant.ParticipantNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: If you format your query (which I have done for you), it should be quite evident why the identifier `Participant` can't be found. :)

Comment: However, even after that, your `WHERE` clause strongly implies you're using implicit joins. It's not 1989 any more; come join 2018! [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @AwarPulldozer Seems like you wrote your own query.  So what else do you need?

Answer (score -3):

SQL Server performs sort, intersect, union, and difference operations using in-memory sorting and hash join technology. Using this type of query plan, SQL Server supports vertical table partitioning, sometimes called columnar storage.

SQL Server employs three types of join operations:

Nested Loops joins
Merge joins
Hash joins
Join Fundamentals
By using joins, you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on logical relationships between the tables. Joins indicate how Microsoft SQL Server should use data from one table to select the rows in another table.

A join condition defines the way two tables are related in a query by:

Specifying the column from each table to be used for the join. A typical join condition specifies a foreign key from one table and its associated key in the other table.
Specifying a logical operator (for example, = or <>,) to be used in comparing values from the columns.
Inner joins can be specified in either the FROM or WHERE clauses. Outer joins can be specified in the FROM clause only. The join conditions combine with the WHERE and HAVING search conditions to control the rows that are selected from the base tables referenced in the FROM clause.

Follow this link to help you understand joins better in mssql:
[link to joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on SO (and often deleted). I've linked to the above site in the comments on the question already as well, however, if you want to improve your answer then please include the relevant parts from the page. This means that if the link ever dies you're answer is still useful to others.